# Can't associate Office 365 with Azure subscription

Tags: azure, office365

For my company, I have an Office 365 E3 subscription (not trial). 
My office 365 account is also global admin.

Now I would like to use Office 365 API. According to the getting started tutorial I was told to associate Azure with Office 365.

So I when go to Office 365 Admin panel then click to Azure AD. I end up with Azure Sign up screen however the screen is empty. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing whatsoever to do with **programming** which this site is all about ...

Comment: Perhaps you are right but the funny thing is Office365 people state that we should ask questions to stack overflow. Check out other questions with office365 tags. You will then understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be my browser is blocking third party  cookies . When I turned that option, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a development question, but as there is no O365 forum, an answer can still be provided, which this site is all about.

You need to go on this website https://manage.windowsazure.com/ and register to access your Azure AD. It takes few minutes to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

there's a new getting-started flow that might make this easier in the future, in case others hit this as well on http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis.